# How to estimate OOB error rate from OOB score for Regression problem

Tags: python-3.x, regression, random-forest

I am using random forest regression package in sklearn, python. My dataset contains 146 samples in training and 38 samples in testing set. I have trained the model but I want to plot the OOB error rate with number of trees by varying num_features. The curve which gives least OOB error for particular number of trees will be chosen for optimal model parameters for testing set.

I have calculated OOB error rate as (1-OOB score). But the OOB error rate is decreasing from 0.8 to 0.625 for the best curve. That means my OOB score is not improving much even with large number of trees (300). I want to know whether I am following the right procedure to plot OOB error rate or not. And how can I improve the performance of my random forest model

```
ensemble_clfs = [

    ("max_features=1",
        RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=125,max_depth=5,min_samples_split=6,
                               warm_start=True,max_features=1,min_samples_leaf=3,
                               oob_score=True,random_state=42)),
    ("max_features=2",
        RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=125,max_depth = 5,min_samples_split=8,
                               warm_start=True, max_features=2,min_samples_leaf=3,
                               oob_score=True,
                               random_state=42)),
     ("max_features=3",
        RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=125,max_depth 
 =5,min_samples_split=8,
                               warm_start=True, max_features=3,min_samples_leaf=3,
                               oob_score=True,
                               random_state=42))
]

error_rate = OrderedDict((label, []) for label, _ in ensemble_clfs)

min_estimators = 10
max_estimators = 300

for label, clf in ensemble_clfs:
    for i in range(min_estimators, max_estimators + 1):
        clf.set_params(n_estimators=i)
        clf.fit(X, Y)

        # Record the OOB error for each `n_estimators=i` setting.
        ''''''
        oob_error = 1 - clf.oob_score_
        error_rate[label].append((i, oob_error))
        ''''''
```

I expect the OOB error rate to go down as low as possible, may be upto 0.1 which says my validation is accurate. So that I can apply it to testing set[OOB error rate with number of trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkNkq.png)

Comment: Have you tried simple train/test split to get error for your forests? to see if the problem actually lies in poor prediction accuracy of the model, not bcz OOB calculation is wrong

Comment: @ShihabShahriar Do you mean to split the training set further into validation set and check prediction accuracy on validation set instead of using OOB error??

Comment: yes..............................